# MongoDB - Collection-level roles

Tags: mongodb

I have a *trouble*.
I'm trying to apply a **role** to **user**.
I want the user only find, insert, remove and update specific collection

I'm doing this.

1. Create role:

   db.createRole({role:'user_role_col',privileges:[{resource:{db:'something_else', collection: 'col_something_else'}, actions: ['find','remove','insert','update']}], roles: []});
   .
2. Create user with that role:

   db.createUser({user: 'user_col',pwd: '1234',roles: [{role: "user_role_col", db: "something_else"}]})
   .

When I created **role** and **user**, I stay on **something_else** database (*use something_else*)

0 errors got, but I can only read **col_something_else**, I cannot remove, update, or insert :(

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the following commands replicates what you did. Here I'm creating the role and user in the `test` database:

```
> use test

> db.createRole({role: 'testRole', privileges: [{resource: {db:'test', collection:'test'}, actions:['find','update','insert','remove']}], roles: []})

> db.createUser({user:'testUser',pwd:'password',roles:[{role:'testRole', db:'test'}]})
```

I would then have to quit the `mongo` shell and re-authenticate using the new credentials. However, the `authenticationDatabase` parameter must point to the `test` database, since that's where I created the role and the user:

```
$ mongo -u testUser -p password --authenticationDatabase test

> db.test2.insert({a:1})  //try inserting to a non-"test" collection
unauthorized

> db.test2.find()  //try find on a non-"test" collection
unauthorized

> db.test.insert({a:1})  //insert into "test" collection
Inserted 1 record(s)

> db.test.updateMany({},{$set:{a:2}})  //update "test" collection
{
  "acknowledged": true,
  "matchedCount": 1,
  "modifiedCount": 1
}

> db.test.find()  //find on "test" collection
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5a0bcfa4322032cfcc3a69c6"),
  "a": 2
}

> db.test.deleteOne({a:2})  //delete from "test" collection
{
  "acknowledged": true,
  "deletedCount": 1
}

> db.test.drop()  //try to drop "test" collection
2017-11-15T16:32:07.715+1100 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: drop failed: {
  "ok": 0,
  "errmsg": "not authorized on test to execute command { drop: \"test\" }",
  "code": 13,
  "codeName": "Unauthorized"
}
```

I found that the new custom role (`testRole`) is authorized correctly. This is using MongoDB 3.4.10.